# How to link libs once only in GCC?

Tags: gcc, linker

Pardon my question, I am a beginner to GCC. I have a framework project that holds source code for multiple subcomponents.

The structure is below:

```
Framework/
makefile //Master makefile in root
    Component1/
       src/
       bin/
       makefile
    Component2/
       src/
       bin/
       makefile
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ComponentN/
       src/
       bin/
       makefile
```

Now each makefiles in ComponentN/ each of directories will compile the code in its respective src/ and output .o to bin/ directory.

The root makefile however searches all the .o files recursively and links them all into one executable named 'framework'

**Problem:**

For code dependencies like glib,gdbus,gio I have to link them once when creating .o objects, in each of the component projects.

Plus I have to link the dependencies again when linking all the .o into one executable at root level.

Why do I have to do it twice? I am interested in understanding the internal mechanics.

As per request I am putting in makefile of the individual component libs that products *.o files

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g3
LIBS = `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
BINDIR = bin
OUTOBJ = $(addprefix $(BINDIR)/, objex.o)

$(BINDIR)/%.o : %.c
               $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LIBS)

all: $(OUTOBJ)

$(OUTOBJ): | $(BINDIR)

$(BINDIR):
          mkdir $(BINDIR)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
      rm bin/*
```

Comment: What do you mean by _I have to_? What happens if you don't link them in the second time?

Comment: @Vladislavlvanishin The gcc throws an error saying the symbol not found or something of that sort. Don't remember the exact wordings, but it will fail to resolve structures and methods borrowed from external libs.

Comment: How does the first per-subproject "linking" look like, could you show an example of the command? Usually `.o` files are not linked, they are just the compilation outputs, no need to provide libraries at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Object files (`.o`) are created by compilation commands, e.g.

```
gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c ...
g++ -c -o baz.o baz.cpp ...
```

`-c` means *compile; don't link*. No linkage happens in the creation of
object files by the compiler. Any linkage options that you add to a compilation
command, e.g.

```
gcc -c -o foo.o foo.c -L/my/libs -lbar -lgum
```

are simply ignored.

Linkage options are acted on by a linkage command, which creates a *program*, or shared/dynamic
library, by linking together object files and libraries, e.g.

```
gcc -o prog foo.o baz.o -L/my/libs -lbar -lgum
gcc -shared -o libfoobaz.so foo.o baz.o -L/my/libs -lbar -lgum
```

So:

> For code dependencies like glib,gdbus,gio I have to link them once when creating .o objects, in each of the component projects.

No you don't, and you can't.

**Later**

With sight of the problem makefile it is quite clear how to eliminate
the `$(LIBS)` reference from the compilation recipe, and what has been stopping you. The makefile defines:

```
LIBS = `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
```

which is a mistake. That makes `$(LIBS)` expand to the standard output of the
command:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0
```

which is a single string containing both the *compilation options* required
for compiling source that `#include`-s the `glib-2.0` API (on account of `--cflags`)
and also the *linkage options* required for linking a program or shared library
against `libglib-2.0` (on account of `--libs`). On my system that is:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0
```

of which the compilation options alone would be output by:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
```

and the linkage options alone would be output by:

```
$ pkg-config --libs glib-2.0
-lglib-2.0
```

But because both sets of options are available only together through the expansion
of `$(LIBS)` you cannot successfully *compile* without passing the 
linkage option `-lglib-2.0`, which is redundant and ignored.

As your make tool is evidently GNU Make, the makefile (which BTW is not that bad!) would be better written as:

**Makefile**

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -g3 $(shell pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0)
BINDIR := bin
SRCS := objex.c
OUTOBJ := $(addprefix $(BINDIR)/, $(SRCS:.c=.o))

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OUTOBJ)

$(BINDIR)/%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

$(OUTOBJ): | $(BINDIR)

$(BINDIR):
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OUTOBJ)
```

which dispenses with `LIBS` and runs from scratch like:

```
$ make
mkdir -p bin
gcc -c objex.c -g3 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -o bin/objex.o
```

Note a few other improvements:-

The use of immediate expansion (`:=`) wherever applicable in preference to unnecessary
recursive expansion (`=`). See [6.2 The Two Flavors of Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html)

The use of direct shell substitution *by make* - `$(shell command)` - in preference to backtick-expansion in
recipe execution. See [8.13 The shell Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Shell-Function.html).

`all`, like `clean` is a [phony target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html)
and you need to tell make that it is, to avoid the booby-trap in which something creates a file called `all` in
the project directory without you noticing and make mysteriously stops detecting any work for it to do.

With your `clean` receipe:

```
clean:
      rm bin/*
```

`make clean` will fail if ever run except following a successful build. The recipe
is replaced with `$(RM) $(OUTOBJ)`, using GNU Make's predefined delete macro, which
won't fail.

Finally, remember that your *linkage* recipe, wherever it is, *does* need the library options for `glib-2.0`,
which you should provide in its makefile with:

```
LIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs glib-2.0) # ...and any more library options required
```

for use in a recipe similar to:

```
prog: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LIBS)
```

---

[1] Strictly, preprocessor options should appear in the definition of `CPPFLAGS`
(C PreProcessor Flags), not to be confused with `CXXFLAGS` (C++ compilation options).

[2] Strictly, linkage options other than libraries should appear in the definition
of `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: Without linking, the gcc gives an error when I compile the components into object files. It complains that the referenced objects of gio/glib and methods are not resolvable. Only by specifying them to pkg-config will gcc create the object files.

Comment: Here's the full command that is executed from makefile: gcc -g3 -o objex comp1.o comp2.o comp3.o 'pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0 gio-unix-2.0'

Comment: I "manually" resolved the above command from the makefile. There might be slight errors in the actual command executed vs what I put out above, but it is enough to give the big picture.

Comment: Unless I am mixing up "linking" with something else above.

Comment: The command you've posted in your comment is a linkage command, not a compilation
command. It outputs a program, `objex`, not an object file. You linkage command needs your library options. Your compilation commands do not.
Your difficulty is unlikely to be soluble unless you improve your question with
a [mcve].

Comment: I made a stupid mistake of reading from the root makefile. Here's how my component makefile looks.

Comment: OUTOBJ = $(addprefix $(BINDIR)/, objex.o)

Comment: $(BINDIR)/%.o : %.c

Comment: TAB >>            $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(LIBS)

Comment: The output is definitely an *.o object file that goes into bin/ directory. That much I can positively assert.

Comment: @Ace See extended answer

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I have posted the full makefile as per your request. I am still reviewing your detailed answer before I come back to you with my points/response. But in the meantime please have a look at the component makefile that I added to the answer in full form.

Comment: And you are correct in saying it is not proficiently written. Though I am intimately familiar with C (Such a basic language after all!), the makefiles/dbus and other C based *nix frameworks - I am tackling them for the first time. Id definitely like to refine this crude starting form.

Comment: @Ace That's what was needed :)